# Why is justify-content: space-between not working even though I have included display: flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

CSS:

```css
.navbar {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: center;
    height: 10vh;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="burger">
        <div class="layer1"></div>
        <div class="layer2"></div>
        <div class="layer3"></div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I was expecting the items to have spacing between them but they don't. Any suggestions?

I have tried `.navbar .burger` as the selector but it doesn't format quite well.

Comment: Can you please provide your HTML as well? A working example would be helpful.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and provide an [mre], preferably using a Stack Snippet (icon has `<>` in it).

Comment: You have to close your nav: `</nav>`

Comment: I;m not clear what you are wanting. Are you trying to draw a burger?

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want:

```css
.burger {
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-content: center;
        height: 10vh;
        background-color: blue;
        color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="burger">
    <div class="layer1">Text1</div>
    <div class="layer2">Text2</div>
    <div class="layer3">Text3</div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the flexbox settings to the **direct** parent of the items which you want to affect, in your case `.burger`:

```css
.burger {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: center;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="burger">
    <div class="layer1">Entry 1</div>
    <div class="layer2">Entry 2</div>
    <div class="layer3">Entry 3</div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks! I believe this was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want space-between if your Flexbox and properties (`justify-content: space-between`) are toggled to only ONE element: `div.burguer`?

I don't think that you miss some info to us, just forgot to close your `<nav>` with `</nav>`.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .navbar {
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-content: center;
            height: 10vh;
            background-color: gray;
        }
        .navbar > div {
            padding: 2px 10px;
            color: white;
        }
        .navbar > div:nth-child(1) {
            background: red;
        }
        .navbar > div:nth-child(2) {
            background: blue;
        }
        .navbar > div:nth-child(3) {
            background: yellow;
            color: black !important;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="layer1">Home</div>
            <div class="layer2">Panel</div>
            <div class="layer3">Contact</div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```